# Solving system of coupled recurrence relations

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

Say you are given a system of $k$ coupled recurrence relations, subject to some initial conditions, that you want to solve. For example,
\begin{align}
A_1(n)&= c_{11}A_1(n-1)+c_{12}A_2(n-1)+\cdots c_{1k}A_k(n-1)\\
A_2(n)&= c_{21}A_1(n-1)+c_{22}A_2(n-1)+\cdots c_{2k}A_k(n-1)\\
&\vdots \\
A_k(n)&=c_{k1}A_1(n-1)+c_{k2}A_2(n-1)+\cdots c_{kk}A_k(n-1)
\end{align}
How would one go about solving this? I tried finding some kind of method of solving these, but almost all of the ones I have seen were for $k=2$ and use some sort of algebraic manipulation and substitution. In this case that would not be feasible. Is there some way to solve these equations, maybe in a similar way that coupled ODEs are solved?

Comment: @ ultrainstinct Write the relation as a matrix equation $A(n) = C A(n-1)$ for the vector $A(n)=(A_{1}(n), A_{2}(n),...,A_{k}(n))$ and the matrix $C = (c_{i,k})$. Then you see that $A(1) = C A(0), A(2) = C A(1) = C^2 A(0), ..., A(n) = C^n A(0)$. Hence the problem boils down to matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matrix notation,

$$A_n=CA_{n-1},$$ and by induction,

$$A_n=C^nA_0.$$

This is indeed an exponential solution, as in the case of differential equations.

Now if $C$ is diagonizable, i.e.
$$C=P\Lambda P^{-1},$$
we have
$$C^n=P\Lambda^{n}P^{-1}$$ which shows that the solution is a linear combination of vectors weighted by exponential factors $\lambda^n$.

Comment: It is also true that Cayley Hamilton lets us write a separate linear recurrence of degree $n$ for each $A_j;$ indeed, the same linear recurrence, just the initial values are different for each $A_j.$ This may or may not be helpful...